# pass a point parameter to a user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control that needs a Point. For example for location.
`<controls:MyUserControl Location="Point"/>`
**I'm not using binding and Location is an object not a Point because It can be everthing.**

I tried:
`<controls:MyUserControl Location="1,1"/>`
`<controls:MyUserControl Location="1 1"/>`
and
`<controls:MyUserControl Location={1 1}/>`
none of them works. Is using converters are my only ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Location would be of type Point, writing Location="1,1" or Location="1 1" would have worked, because [Point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.point) already has a Type converter assigned.

But as it is of type `object`, you will have to construct a point instance explicitely.

This should work using [Property Element Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#property-element-syntax):

```
<controls:MyUserControl>
  <controls:MyUserControl.Location>
    <Point X="1" Y="1" />
  <controls:MyUserControl.Location>
</controls:MyUserControl>
```